# Behaviour of Hikari setConnectionTimeout

Tags: hikaricp

Just looking for an explanation of rationale for this bit of code (PoolUtiltites:293 in version 2.2.4):

```
dataSource.setLoginTimeout((int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Math.min(1000L, connectionTimeout)));
```

This code and the setConnectionTimeout method means that I get this behaviour:

- connectionTimeout == 0, then loginTimeout = Integer.MAX_VALUE
- connectionTimeout > 0 && < 100, then HikariConfig throws IllegalArgumentException
- connectionTimeout >= 100 && <= 1000, then loginTimeout = connectionTimeout
- connectionTeimout > 1000, then loginTimeout = 1000

That looks really weird to me!

It's almost like the Math.min should be Math.max ???

In my current project I'd like to fail connections after 30s, which is impossible in the current setup.

I'm using the 4.1 postgres jdbc driver, but I think this is not relevant to the issue above.

Many thanks - and cool pooling library!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, there are a couple of moving parts here.  First, `Math.min()` is a bug, it should be `Math.max()`.  In light of that (it will be fixed) consider the following:

It is important to note that connections are *created* asynchronously in the pool.  The `setConnectionTimeout()` sets the maximum time (in milliseconds) that a call to `getConnection()` will wait for a connection before timing out.

The DataSource `loginTimeout` is the maximum time that physical connection initiation to the database can take before timing out.  Because HikariCP obtains connections asynchronously, if the connection attempt fails, HikariCP will continue to retry, but your calls to `getConnection()` will timeout appropriately.  We are using the connectionTimeout in kind of a double duty for `loginTimeout`.

For example, lets say the pool is completely empty, and you have configured a `connectionTimeout` of 30 seconds.  When you call `getConnection()` HikariCP, realizing that there are no idle connections available, starts trying to obtain a new one.  There is little point in having a `loginTimeout` exceeding 30 seconds, in this case.

The intent of the `Math.max()` call is to ensure that we never set `loginTimeout` to `0` if the user has configured `connectionTimeout` to `250ms`.  `TimeUnit.MILLESECONDS.toSeconds()` would return `0` without the `Math.max()`.  If the user has configured a `connectionTimeout` of `0`, meaning they never want to timeout, the time conversion of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` results in several thousand years as a timeout (*virtually* never).

Having said that, and in light of how HikariCP connections to the database are obtained asynchronously, even without the `Math.max()` fix, you should be able to achieve application-level connection timeouts of 30s.  Unless physical connections to your database exceed 1000ms you would be unaffected by the `Math.min()`.

We are putting out a 2.2.5-rc3 release candidate in the next few hours.  I will slot this fix in.

Comment: That all makes sense, thanks! It'd be a good plan to separate the new connection overhead timeout from the how long do I want to wait for the pool to hand me a connection timeout. In my case I'm a long way from my DB (3s to open a connection), but once my connections are established I can't wait around for them if they're busy ...

Comment: If your ``connectionTimeout`` is 30s, the ``loginTimeout`` would also be 30s.  It would only be an issue if your database takes a long time to connect (3s), but you are only willing to wait, for example, for 1s from connections from the pool.  While this might be possible in some scenarios, it seems mostly like an edge case.  Unlike some pools with dozens of options, we try hard to keep HikariCP dead-nut simple.  Still, we will take it under consideration.  Thanks.